# Trying to update the content of a JLabel

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I'm back again with a simpler question! I'd like the content of this JLabel (triedLettersLA) to update periodically throughout the application (I have that part handled).

But I'd like to ADD text to the label. NOT rewrite it entirely. For example.. If the text said "Letters Tried: ", I'd want to add "N", and "X", and then "H" on three separate occasions. So at the end, it'd look like this "Letters Tried: N X H". Here's what I have, and it's totally not working..

This is way up top,

```
JLabel triedLettersLA = new JLabel("Tried letters:");
public boolean used[] = new boolean[26];
```

And this is lower down in my code..

```
StringBuffer missedLetter = new StringBuffer();
for (int le = 0; le <= 25; le++) {
     if (used[le]) missedLetter.append((char)(le + 'a'));
     String triedLettersLA.getText(t);
     triedLettersLA.setText(t + " " + missedLetter.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 4):

<strike>The code you posted makes no sense (nor could it ever compile).</strike> Well, it would compile now, possibly.

That being said, a `String` in Java is *immutable*; you can't change it. To change the text of a `JLabel` you need to create a new `String` and call the `JLabel`'s `setText()` method.

```
String old = triedLettersLA.getText();
String newString = old + " N"; // this creates a new String object
triedLettersLA.setText(newString);
```

Comment: This will serve to add "N" to the text. Expanding on it a little, if you want the letters to always be sorted (as above) start the function by using triedLettersLA.setText("Tried letters:"); -then you can loop across the letters.

Comment: You know that `new` is a reserved word right? I suggest you change it, for example, to newStr.

Comment: @Boro - after a few gin and tonics, apparently I stop noticing such things ;) Thanks.

Comment: No worries. (+1) for the answer and for including the suggested correction. All the best :)

Answer (score 0):

Nonsence code:

```
String triedLettersLA.getText(t);
```

Change it to:

```
String t = triedLettersLA.getText();
```